# getElementById not working in textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to retrieve the latlng of a particular place in google map and I wanted it to be shown in the textbox so that I can use php to insert it to mySQL database. But it seems like my method somehow wasn't correct. It does not display if I use textbox but it display when I use div.
Below are the following codes:

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<br/><br/><br/>Location 1 coordinates are: "+location1+"";
```

HTML

```
<center><input type="text" id="test" value="" size="30"/></div></center>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Input tags cannot have a .innerhtml. they're singleton tags and can never have 'child' elements'.

Comment: When or how is your javascript being called? On button click? Textbox blur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.value`, not `.innerHTML`, to set the value of a text input element.

Comment: Thanks alot. I guess I have to revisit and study the basics of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.value` property.

```
document.getElementById("test").value = "<br/><br/>...";
```

But of course this will give you HTML markup, not DOM elements as you may be expecting.

---

If you want line breaks, you need to use a `<textarea>` instead of an `<input>`.

```
document.getElementById("my_textarea").value = "\n\n\nLocation 1 coordinates are: " + location1;
```

Note that you don't need the closing `+ ""`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set innerHTML property of an input Object. use Value property instead.

```
document.getElementById("test").value = "<br/><br/><br/>Location 1 coordinates are: "+location1+"";
```

Also using html tag is not recomended in input element. Its used for text. So use it like

```
document.getElementById("test").value = "Location 1 coordinates are: "+location1+"";
```